# Remove colon after "in" only for @inproceedings

Tags: biblatex

My codes are:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
% BibTeX bibliography file
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\setlength{\bibhang}{5\p@}%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3\p@}%
\def\bibfont{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont}%
\renewcommand{\RNfont}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{acerbi2017practical,
  title={Practical Bayesian optimization for model fitting with Bayesian adaptive direct search},
  author={Acerbi, Luigi and Ma, Wei Ji},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 31st International Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems},
  pages={1834--1844},
  year={2017}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}

\cite{acerbi2017practical} 

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

But, I need the following change in that:

> 1. Should remove the colon after the text "In", this should applicable to the entry which comes `inproceedings` only, not for others like `article` and `book` style entries

For better clarification:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have voted this question down. In at least two of your previous questions (one of which is now deleted), I explicitly asked you to ask about only one issue per question, because that makes things easier to answer and more useful for future visitors. Yet this question still consists of at least three different issues.

Comment: @moewe Sorry for the mistake, I've understood your comments in a wrong way, now modified the question as you advised, please suggest

Comment: Along with your suggestion, please advise which documentation should I read for better understanding about `biblatex`

Comment: I changed the downvote to an upvote. For most of the things you probably want to do there is not a lot of documentation available. (In this case, the `biblatex` documentation has `\intitlepunct`, but you sort of have to know that you are looking for it to find it.) You have to look at the code of the style(s) you use and chase definitions of bibmacros and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The punctuation after "in" is controlled by `\intitlepunct`, which we can redefine to include `\ifentrytype` so that the definition is different for `@inproceedings` and other types.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=nyt,
  sortcites=true,
  autopunct=true,
  autolang=hyphen,
  abbreviate=false,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcolon\space}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{acerbi2017practical,
  title     = {Practical Bayesian optimization for model fitting with Bayesian adaptive direct search},
  author    = {Acerbi, Luigi and Ma, Wei Ji},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 31st International Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems},
  pages     = {1834--1844},
  year      = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{acerbi2017practical,sigfridsson,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Luigi Acerbi and Wei Ji Ma. “Practical Bayesian optimization for model fitting with Bayesian adaptive direct search”. In Proceedings of the 31st International Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems. 2017, pages 1834–1844 (cited on page 1).]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working also thanking for removing `downvote`

Comment: Sorry to ask, from where the tag `\intitlepunct" came from, please advise

Comment: @MadyYuvi `\intitlepunct` is documented in the `biblatex` manual and defined and used in [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def).